# Neighbor leaves his positive terminal disconnected - dangerous?

Tags: electrical, battery, car

A guy who owns a neighboring car in the communal parking garage I park in disconnects the positive side of the battery when leaving his car for a few days at a time.

Is this dangerous? If so, under what circumstances could this cause an accident?

Comment: Your previous question was about the *negative* terminal. If the battery is disconnected, there is no circuit. The chance of a spark when disconnecting or reconnecting is the same, whichever terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If he has a classic car with a positive ground (as opposed to almost all if not all modern cars that have a negative ground) then there is no danger and that is the proper terminal to disconnect.

On the other hand, if his car has a negative ground this can be dangerous. The danger is present *while disconnecting and reconnecting* the battery. If while loosening/tightening the terminal the wrench contacts the body of the car or another grounded metal component, a completed circuit is created. This will just about instantly heat up the wrench and terminal and other contacted metal (like maybe a ring he is wearing). I have seen battery terminals melt in seconds when someone wasn't paying attention. Should the short circuit not be immediately terminated, this poses a serious safety risk to him as he is doing it.

Comment: The same danger also exists while re-connecting the battery.

Comment: @John very true! I will edit my answer.